# percona innobackup failed

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get percona innobackup but I'm struggling with this since 4hrs. Tried all possible ways from many forums. interms of changing my.cnf, parsing arguments but still not able to get this fixed. Have any one fixed this before.? Please help!

```
sh: xtrabackup_51: command not found
innobackupex: fatal error: no 'mysqld' group in MySQL options
```

Answer (score 0):

DArn. Found it. I should have moved the binaries to /usr/bin/* to automatically pick when the name is called. That made the file not to execute it.  Now all is good.